# Which Xcode object to use to display simple table fetched from SQL statement?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am building a type of fantasy football app where users can join other leagues to compete in against friends.

At the moment I have been using Stack Views with a Scroll View to organise on screen labels.

What object would be best for me to use in order to display the different leagues that someone is apart of? (This will come from a fetched SQL)

It only needs to display a list of the leagues they are in (maybe position also) and then allow the user to tap whichever league they want to 'view more details of' (i.e full standings table etc) at which point the screen will change.

Please see the image link for a clearer idea
[Mock-up design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEkUk.png)

fig.1 - the leagues which when tapped the screen will change and that leagues' info will appear (fig.3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionview) for grids.
[UITableView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview) for lists.

Or just UICollectionView for both.

You can nest collectionviews and tableviews inside of your stackview. Or you can use multiple cell types / header types, up to you.

Comment: Excellent! So for 'Screen 1' I would next a UITableView inside of my current set of Stack Views, and then when it changes to Screen 2, use UICollection View? Is that correct?

Comment: Yup. It will be a bit tricky if the height of your table / collection view is dynamic. You'll have to keep a reference to the height constraint and update it as needed so it displays correctly in the stack view.

Comment: hmm. it probably will be dynamic as someone might be in 1 league, or they might be in 5....

Answer (score 0):

You can use UITableView for Leagues part and For grid part UICollectionView is perfect. do not enable scrolling in it. as the value will be constant.

Comment: I already have a ScrollView as the content will be more than my screen height.  Is that what you mean? or are you meaning scrolling on the UITableView/CollectionView specifically?

Comment: I'm watching a tutorial on UITableView's but they all seem to use UITableViewController rather than UITableView.  I already have my ViewController set up.  I don't seem to have the 'identifier' option in my attributes.  Am I going down the wrong path?  video: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=trkuhgbxF44)